# How to find keyword in audio file and deliver timestamps

Tags: tensorflow, audio-processing

I wonder how to find a certain keyword (potentially multiple times) in a (long, lets say 1-2 hours) audio file with their corresponding time stamps of start and end of it.

Let's say we do it with Tensorflow as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio). The problems I see are the following: In reality the keyword we use to train can be a bit longer or shorter (for example you can say "no" or "nooooo", ranging therefore from 0.1s to 3s maybe). In the link they use padding for that so the input for training and inference is always in the same shape.

So what is in reality the best way to deal with:

1. Different input lengths of the audio snippets to train? Padding and cutting might destroy important information or add nonsensical "emptiness".
2. How to find/run inference in the long audio file? Moving window with a resolution of 16kHz would be the obvious way but that can't be an efficient way.
3. How to then get the timestamps?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is more suited to the signal processing branch of Stack Exchange? Have you tried taking the power spectrum of the first few occurrences manually and then matching those to the power spectrum for the rest of the audio file? All the places that have a high correlation coefficient are the places that word occurs. Not sure about the accuracy though. Some form of short time power spectra analysis should do the trick.

Comment: Hi shounak, thanks for the answer. Yes, I thought about signal processing as well but I was more wondering how to handle it with the basis of TF and training a more generalist approach.